# Can't Install Ubuntu with Windows, have 2 errors

Tags: dual-boot, kernel

I'm new with ubuntu and i trying to install it with windows 10 (dual boot)

I downloaded the ISO and "burned" it with Rufus and an USB.
I created an empty partition for ubuntu.

When i'm trying to install it, this appears:
[image]

So i investigated about that on Internet and found that i had to add this to the kernel parameters "nouveau.modeset=0" (press "e" in GRUB, add that line and reboot)

The first error appeared again for 2 seconds and then this:
[image]

This is my computer:
Intel i7, Gigabyte g1 sniper, HDD, GTX 1070

Comment: And then it stops doing anything? Just stays like that?  How long did you give it? Live disks like the installer can sometimes boot real sloooooooowly.

Comment: Yes, it stops and do nothing.
I found on internet about "nomodeset". i had to press "e" on "install ubuntu" and remove the line "quiet splash" and add "nomodeset" and press f10.
After that it was possible to install (i did in a second disk).When it finished, and tried to open ubuntu through Grub, it fails.
This appears:

b5: recovery journal
b5: clearing orphaned inode 274861 (uid=108, gid=114, mode=0100664, size=2280)
b5: clearing orphaned inode 274862 (uid=108, gid=114, mode=0100664, size=2280)
b5: clean, 223894/1839600 files, 1300612/7351808 blocks

Comment: And now CANT open windows! (didnt erase it)
Help please